# python aes encrypt/decrypt does not return the same results

Tags: python, cryptography, aes, malformed

below code sample does not return the original text after encrypt/decrypt operation and I am trying to figure it out why

```
from Crypto.Cipher import AES

text = """This is plain text 
to use.
It should be exqctly 128 characters long to avoid padding and it is split
with new lines as in 
file"""

password = "password........"

block = 32
mode = AES.MODE_CBC

enc = AES.new(password, mode)

encrypted = enc.encrypt(text)

print "ORIGINAL: " + text

print "ENCRYPTED: " + str(encrypted)

print "DECRYPTED: " + str(enc.decrypt(encrypted))
```

can one tell why first part of the text is malformed ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think, you need to reset the initialisation vector (*IV*), in order to get the desired result. The easist way might be to create a new AES object for decrypting:

```
enc = AES.new(password, mode)
encrypted = enc.encrypt(text)
print "ORIGINAL: " + text
print "ENCRYPTED: " + str(encrypted)
dec = AES.new(password, mode)
print "DECRYPTED: " + str(dec.decrypt(encrypted))
```

Comment: can't you explicitly set and get the IV? Better to get the IV of the encrypter and set the IV for the decrypter.

Comment: You can set it in the constructor (third parameter to `AES.new`). I think the current implementation uses a default IV (not a random one), so it's not strictly necessary to copy it from the encrypter to the decrypter (note, this would have to be done *before* the encryption!). For security reasons, it would be best to use a different (random) IV for each encryption, but you need to pass it somehow to the decrypter, so it might not be worth the additional effort ... See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initialization_vector for more info.